# create-react-app fails for various NodeJS versions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, ubuntu, npm

I am trying to create a React app as per [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04). However, whichever node version I choose with nvm it always fails with an error. v16.19.0:

```
Creating a new React app in /home/user/react-deploy.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

(#########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠸ reify:fsevents: sill reify mark deleted [ '/home/user/react-deploy/node_modules/fsevents' ]
Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting react-deploy/ from /home/user
Done.
```

With node v14.21.0, it gets stuck at

```
[   ...............] | fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule source-map@0.6.1 checking installable status
```

v14.15.0:

```
[      ............] | diffTrees: sill install generateActionsToTake
```

v18.13.0 and v18.0.0:

```
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
```

My guess is, my Ubuntu version may be too old (18.04) or I should not have done `sudo npm clean -f` in the past.

### Edit

I found out that the error occurs trying to install `react-scripts`.